# How to calculate the Euclidean distance between a vector and a vector space?

Tags: numpy

I have a vector (v) and a vector space "W" containing two vectors:

- v = (2.3, -1.2, 4.1, 6.3)
- W = {(3.5, 0.1, 2.6, 8.2), (2.0, -2.0, 0.4, 6.9)}

I want to calculate the distance:

1. d1(v,w) for every w in W
2. d2(v,w) for every w in W
3. d3(v,w) for every w in W

My code is the following, yet I'm not sure if it is doing what it is supposed to do. Am I accessing the vectors in W in the right way?

```
v = np.array([2.3, -1.2, 4.1, 6.3])
w = np.array([(3.5, 0.1, 2.6, 8.2),(2.0, -2.0, 0.4, 6.9)]
dist1 = np.linalg.norm(v-w[0])
dist2 = np.linalg.norm(v-w[1])
dist3 = np.linalg.norm(v-w)
print(dist1, dist2, dist3)
```

Comment: You computed the distance of 'v' for every vector in the set 'W', not sure what 'dist3' would be. The vectorspace spanned by the vectors in 'W' consists of all possible linear combinations of vectors in 'W'. Thus you need to find the vector 'w' in the vectorspace spanned by 'W' that has the minimal distance to 'v'.

Comment: How are `d1`, `d2` and `d3` defined in the original problem anyway?